# received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement. Received has value: null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

Here is the component code :

```
function SignUpPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <input name="userName" />
    </>
  );
}
export default SignUpPage;
```

testing the same:

```
 it("has input", () => {
  render(<SignUpPage />);
  const input = screen.queryByRole("input", { name: /userName/i });
  expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

but throws an error as:

```
received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
Received has value: null
```

how to get by role by input element?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input elements don't have "input" role by default. And input is an abstract role, you shouldn't use it, according by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/input_role)

> The input role is an abstract role. It must not be used by web
> authors.

You can use "textbox" role instead, for example.

And your using of queryByRole is correct, according to the [documentations](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/)

> If you only query for a single element with getByText('The name') it's
> oftentimes better to use getByRole(expectedRole, { name: 'The name'
> }).

**Update**
In your case it's better to use other queries like getByLabelText, getByTestId or getByPlaceholderText

1.

```
 <input name="userName" aria-label="Username" />

 it("has input", () => {
  render(<SignUpPage />);
  const input = screen.queryByLabelText("Username");
  expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

2. 

```
 <input name="userName" placeholder="Username" />

 it("has input", () => {
  render(<SignUpPage />);
  const input = screen. getByPlaceholderText("Username");
  expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

3. 

```
 <input name="userName" data-testid="usernameInput" />

 it("has input", () => {
  render(<SignUpPage />);
  const input = screen. getByTestId("usernameInput");
  expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: thanks for links, yeah its better to use `queryBy` in this scenario since `getByRole` might throw error if element not found where as `queryBy` returns `null`, then we can check for - `expect(match).not.toBeInTheDocument()` or `expect(match).toBeNull()`  .... more info https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#nottobeinthedocument

Comment: I think it's better to use getByRole in this case, because we don't expect the input element to disappear. But, I agree, that queryBy is a great solution in some cases.

Comment: I replaced `input` to `textbox`, but getting same error

Comment: Did you replace it in both places?

Comment: No only on spec file. is it require to replace both place?

Comment: yes. As I said before, input by default doesn't have a role

Comment: If I update as `<input type="text" role="textbox" name="userName" />` getting an error as `The element input has an implicit role of textbox. Defining this explicitly is redundant and should be avoided.`

Comment: can you update the answer both test and answer clearly please?

Comment: In your case, it's better to use other queries like getByTitle/getByPlaceholderText, etc., I suppose.

Comment: Ok, I will add some examples to my answer